# Properly formatting the table after scraped by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python.

I have been trying to scrape a table from http://www.phc4.org/reports/utilization/inpatient/CountyReport20192C001.htm. The targeted table is titled as "Utilization by Body System".

I was able to capture the table by using BeautifulSoup; however, the **scraped** dataframe has been driving me crazy and I could not find a way to address the issue.

My code:

```
import re
import bs4 as bs4
import urllib.request
source=urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.phc4.org/reports/utilization/inpatient/CountyReport20192C001.htm').read()
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
#find the county utilization table by MDC 
#using the parental tag scrapling method, find the exact table index then save the parental table
table_mdc=soup.find(text=re.compile("Utilization by Body System")).findParent('table')
# print (table_mdc)
# #constuct the table
for row in table_mdc.find_all('tr'):
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        print(cell.text)
with open ('utilization.txt','w') as r:
    for row in table_mdc.find_all('tr'):
        for cell in row.find_all('td'):
            r.write(cell.text)
```

For instance, the scraped the dataframe is printed as:

```
Utilization by Body System 
MDC Description
Total Cases
Number
Percent
Total Charges
% of Charges
Avg. Charge
Total Days
% of Total Days
Avg. LOS

Total

 
2,594
 
 
100.0%
 
 
$101,757,824
 
 
100.0%
 
 
$39,228
 
 
11,972
 
 
100.0%
 
 
4.6
```

There are so many newlines in its output as well as the txt file. The ideal txt file should be look like this:

(with no "total cases" in the header)

[image]

What should I do to overcome these issues?

Comment: FYI to all web scrapers out there: the past tense of 'scrape' is 'scraped', not 'scrapped'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_html(
    "http://www.phc4.org/reports/utilization/inpatient/CountyReport20192C001.htm", attrs={"id": "dgBodySystem"}, header=0)[0]

print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

[image]